# Opening EF designer with partial diagrams in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, edmx

Recently my team recently upgraded from VS 2010 to VS 2012. At the same time we created a branch of our code base, one that we needed to work on in VS 2010 for legacy support and bug fixes, and the current version that would be worked on 2012. After the upgrade we decided to make use of partial diagrams in our EDMX but a few days later we had to merge that EDMX into a different branch that is opened in VS 2010.

The problem we seem to be having is that the designer for the EDMX will not load in VS2010 now that the partial diagrams are there. Has anyone else experienced this problem? Is it known problem? Any solutions out there? I've tried hitting google but I'm not finding anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the bottom of this [Visual Studio 2012 Compatibility page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747.aspx). You'll find the section "Entity Data Model (EDMX) files" where it seems to be a workaround.

Hope that helps!